# SQL replace č, ć, ž with letter c, z

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, replace, special-characters

I've got a table with column Last Name. I want to change a part of strings in the column.

```
select REPLACE([Last Name],'Ć','s')  FROM myTable1
```

don't work.

If I put this

```
select REPLACE([Last Name],'o','s')  FROM myTable1
```

it is work.

How to change č,ć,ž with another lettter.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: I use microsoft sql

Comment: Works on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below query might give the required output :-

```
select REPLACE([Last Name] COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI,'Ć','s')  FROM myTable1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms184391.aspx) as:

```
COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

So it would be like

```
select REPLACE([Last Name],'Ć','s')  FROM myTable1
COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

Comment: where to put in select?

Comment: @pape:- Update my answer. Please check.

Comment: @pape:- What is the output of this query on your system? `select serverproperty('collation')` and this query `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('yourdatabaseName', 'Collation') SQLCollation;`

Comment: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, but not work if i put collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Comment: how to change in column

Comment: @pape:- You have to change the collation of your database like `ALTER DATABASE DBName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: @pape:- Do make sure before changing the collation on Production env

Comment: I don't know SQL Servers' collations, but aren't you supposed to put the collate clause in the REPLACE, to change the replace behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use N' at the start of string containing such strings,

e.g. `SELECT 'Ā ā Ă ă Ą ą', N'Ā ā Ă ă Ą ą'`

Make the column type nvarchar rather than varchar or nchar for char

For ignore accents use COLLATE clause. 
E.g.:

`SELECT REPLACE([Last Name],'Ć','s')  FROM myTable1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`